# Making app payment direct to account using Corona SDK

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, coronasdk, currency

Is it possible to make the client in the app pay for some service inside the app, and the money go to my bank account (or any other service)? I don't want in app purchases. Its something like paypal or any other method that corona SDK suports. Any help will be appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is a place where you get answers to questions about an actual programmable problem you have faced. I was able to answer you question by googling "Coronasdk paypal" - please do this yourself.

Comment: For Android the answer is YES, for iOS you can only use another payment system then InApp purchase if you are selling none digital goods. So a server, if need by your app, fall within the digital goods section and Apple will only allow you to use InApp Purchases. Since this question is off-topic for stack overflow I'll not go into to much details.